# Is it incorrect to assume alveoli as spherical and distinct, especially when analysing lung inflation/deflation?

Tags: physiology, respiration, lungs

I have recently read the paper "[Laplace’s Law and the Alveolus: A Misconception of Anatomy and a Misapplication of Physics](https://web.archive.org/web/20210131190939/https://journals.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/advan.00024.2002)". To summarise it, here is a section from its abstract:

> The typical representation of the acinus as a “bunch of grapes”
> bears no resemblance to its real anatomy; the alveoli are not independent little
> balloons. Because of the prevalence of this misconception, Laplace’s law, as it
> applies to spheres, has been invoked as a mechanical model for the forces of
> alveolar inflation and as an explanation for the necessity of pulmonary surfactant
> in the alveolus. . . . Alveoli do not readily
> collapse into one another because they are suspended in a matrix of connective
> tissue “cables” and share common, often perforated walls, so there can be no
> pressure differential across them. Surfactant has important functions along planar
> surfaces of the alveolar wall and in mitigating the forces that tend to close the
> small airways. Laplace’s law as it applies to cylinders is an important feature of the
> mechanics of airway collapse, but the law as it applies to spheres is not relevant
> to the individual alveolus.

This paper made many claims that I want to investigate. I have tried reading other papers to make sense of them and it appears fully understanding the lung is still a difficult problem in physiology.

Please could you help me verify if any of the statements put forwards by the paper and listed below are true:

1. The lung's acini should not be thought of as "bunches of grapes". They are instead much more polyhedral. The interalveolar septa contain numerous interalveolar pores that, although some may contain fluid, can equalize the pressures in the lung and allow ventilation of alveoli with blocked airways. So it is more accurate to think of the lung alveoli as a foam or sponge.
2. The application of Laplace's law is then flawed in the traditional analysis of a smaller alveoli connected to a larger alveoli (see the image below for the traditional analysis). The alveoli are not spherical nor can they ever attain unequal pressures due to their interalveolar pores. It is instead the tensile properties of the lung parenchyma that keeps alveoli from collapsing, instead of the variable surface tension generated by surfactant.

[image: Two alveoli of different size branching off of a common airway]

These 2 points the author makes seem to be very fundamental, yet overlooked in the usual teaching of lung physiology, which is why I want to verify whether they are true or not. Additionally I have read a [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20210131200930/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6267411/pdf/418_2018_Article_1747.pdf) that states "In a healthy lung macro- and micromechanical properties
are dominated by surface tension at the alveolar air–liquid interface at low lung volumes while at larger lung volumes extracellular matrix components become stress bearing and define lung structure and mechanics (Bachofen et al. 1987; Wilson and Bachofen 1982; Bachofen and Schürch 2001)". This seems to state that surface tension of alveoli is in fact more important than lung parenchyma when considering lung collapse, contrary to the paper above.

Comment: Not quite getting your point. Applying  Laplace's law, the effect of surfactant should be relevant much more in smallest alveoli than in larger ones or "tubes"? Then, your question asks if alveoli are  interconnected - hence share same pressure, hence same effect of surfactant -  or,  are you assuming this to be a proven fact? If it'd be true ("to think of"...) - the role of surfactant seems over- or underestimated (that''s what your queston is "up to"  that kind of result would interest me.)?

Comment: The paper refutes the traditional idea of surfactant playing the major role in preventing alveoli collapse due to points 1 and 2 I mentioned in my post. I want to know whether points 1 and 2 are actually valid, as this conflicts with what I've been taught about lung physiology. Point 3 is just the author's explanation of what actually happens during lung collapse, and how it is only here the author thinks Laplace's law should be used. In hindsight, I should not have mentioned point 3 in my post as it only adds confusion - I will edit it out.

Comment: Is the following correct understanding? a. interconnecting alveoli lessens - does not heighten -  air pressure thus enforcing surface tension leading to "collapsing" i.e. tightening of alveoli? Hence, according to the paper, surface tension  is less relevant in spite of "bigger impact in smaller spheres.  What is confusing with point 3 and "hindsight", you say?`To me, biggest caveat, paradox is "drum role" of surfactant. If surface tension is heightend by "spooness", then surfactant becomes more, not less, important, correct?

Comment: It appears we are not doing a very good job of understanding each other - I apologise if I have been unclear. I am not putting forth any new ideas, I am just summarising what is in the paper. If you cannot understand my summary of the paper, please read the paper instead. If you do fully comprehend the paper and can comment on the paper's validity, then that is great - I would be very happy if you could post an answer explaining whether you think the paper is valid or not.

Comment: I read the paper, and "all this" I hereby  recommend to anyone into biology of the  lung.Your very question  reflects the gist of the paper: alveoli being interconnected contrary to common textbooks. Do I think if the paper is "valid"? No empirical knowledge - contrary to the author who apparently "on his own" has done autopsies and thought about it.If the answer is "no" to your question I'd find that valid! However, if you'd extend your question into the messing and mixing up in conclusions to be drawn from the empirical findings of the author that would make me want to answer.

Comment: I'm a newbie myself. Guess you should add some reference for the standard knowlege (alveoli are spheres) the author citicizes, and, second, add some searches you have done on any other authors confirming the .author's findings. P.S. You are right about you not having brought  up new ideas. Me neither, just conclusions right or wrong.